# Unable to open file with breakpoint after debug

Tags: .net, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I have a weird problem. Whenever I start to debug and stop the debug if a file has a breakpoint I won't be able to open it directly in Visual Studio.

I have ReSharper 7.1 and StyleCop installed but disabled and installed VS 2012 Update 2 but it didn't fix my problem.

If I click on the breakpoint I get an error:

```
Unable to go to the breakpoint. The ViewManager.ActiveView must be a View contained within the ViewManager.WindowProfile.
```

And if I debug again and Visual Studio has to hit the breakpoint, I get:

```
'TheFile' not found.
You need to find 'TheFile' to view the source for the current call stack frame.
```

The only solution to get my file to open again is to close and reopen Visual Studio.

Answer (score 7):

To stop *ALL* files from being closed after debugging simply go to

```
Tools > Import and Export Settings > Reset Settings
```

This will fix this bug, I have the old settings saved that caused this error but I am unsure what specifically causes it within the settings. After frustratingly searching around for a clear answer to this problem I hope this helps others that might have this issue.

Comment: This one did it for me. Can also be performed from the command prompt using: "devenv /resetsettings"

Answer (score 7):

I had this same error when trying to open one of my .cs files from Visual Studio. It turns out that I had WAY too many files open at once and I must have been hitting some sort of internal limit. After closing all open files in VS it stopped happening for me.

Comment: Closing all tabs solved this for me on VS2019 Pro

Answer (score 2):

I have had several similar debug problems with Reshaper 7.1. Uninstalling it solved my problems. I wont claim that problem was in Reshaper as I have other plugins installed, but other plugins don't make this kind of problems so Reshaper had to go.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and managed to resolve it by checking the solution configuration (right-click the solution and select "Configuration Manager."  It was there I discovered that for debugging purposes the Build checkbox wasn't checked.  Doh.  Checking it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this by deleting the hidden ".vs" folder and restart VS.